# async function blocks my wpf application

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I try to become acquainted with async/await. So I try to write an C#/WPF program to query a database asynchronously without blocking my GUI.

I created an object implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. This object offers a `DataTable` property and this should become changed by my async function. My GUI component has a binding to the `DataTable` property.

My object looks this way:

```
public class AsyncDataDemo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected DataTable data = new DataTable();

    public DataTable Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        protected set
        {
            data = value;
            doPropertyChanged("Data");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void doPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventArgs Arguments = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);
            PropertyChanged(this, Arguments);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected async Task<DataTable> OpenQueryAsync(string ConnectionString, string Query)
    {
        OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString);
        await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(Query, connection);
        DbDataReader dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        DataTable resultData = new DataTable();
        resultData.Load(dataReader);
        connection.Close();
        return resultData;
    }

    public async void RunQueryAsync(string Query)
    {           
            Data = await OpenQueryAsync("<ConectionString>", (Query as string)).ConfigureAwait(false);          
    }
}
```

And at a button click event I call:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    data.RunQueryAsync("SELECT * FROM BigTable");
}
```

This works fine with one exception: the button click blocks my GUI until the data is loaded and I don't understand why.

Can somebody please explain my failure to me? I don't understand why the async function won't run asynchronously?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really need to step through with a debugger to figure out which step is taking a long time. The most likely candidate is `resultData.Load(dataReader);`, the way your code could still be on the UI thread is if every function you call returns a task that is already has `.IsCompleted == true`.

If the task is already completed and you `await` you stay on the UI thread even though you did `ConfigureAwait(false)`. All that needs to happen is `OpenAsync()` and `ExecuteReaderAsync()` need to complete very quickly or complete synchronously (both very possible).

One way you could fix this put the query on a background thread to start instead of waiting on `ConfigureAwait(false)` to do it for you.

```
public async void RunQueryAsync(string Query)
{           
        Data = await Task.Run(() => OpenQueryAsync("<ConectionString>", (Query as string)));          
}
```

I also removed the `ConfigureAwait(false)` because you want your `INotifyPropertyChanged` to happen on the UI thread.

Also you REALLY need to be disposing of your disposable objects.

```
protected async Task<DataTable> OpenQueryAsync(string ConnectionString, string Query)
{
    using(OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(ConnectionString))
    {    
        await connection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

        using(OdbcCommand command = new OdbcCommand(Query, connection))
        using(DbDataReader dataReader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            DataTable resultData = new DataTable();
            resultData.Load(dataReader);
            return resultData;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick.

And also thank you for the hint about my disposable objects. I will do better.

Answer (score 4):

The reason for the behavior you are experiencing is a flaw in the `DbConnection` and `DbCommand` classes which all ADO providers use as base for their specific classes. And the flaw is that by default all the `Async` methods are **synchronous**! It's even documented!

For instance, the documentation for [DbConnnection.OpenAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbconnection.openasync(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The default implementation invokes the **synchronous** Open call and returns a completed task.

and for [DbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.executedbdatareaderasync(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The default implementation invokes the **synchronous** ExecuteReader method and returns a completed task, **blocking the calling thread**.

From what I have seen, only the `SqlServer` provider overrides async methods with a real asynchronous implementation. But since you are using `OleDb` provider, you are out of luck.

Comment: Thank you for the very useful explanation I will keep this in mind.

Comment: @Mike In case it is not clear (combining the info in the two answers), when an async function completes synchronously doing `.ConfigureAwait(false)` has no affect on the flow of the code and you will still be on the UI thread after the `await` call even though you set `.ConfigureAwait(false)`.